# Issue in interface versioning

Tags: c#, .net, interface

My old version of the interface which is exposed to the users is this:

```
public interface IReporter
{
    void  Write(int site, DateTime start, DateTime end);
}
```

Now I want to replace the parameters in the function as below:

```
public interface IReporter
{
    void  Write(int site, SiteLocalDateTime start, SiteLocalDateTime end);
}
```

I want the existing customer to use the old method and the new customer to use the new method.

Any idea on how to achieve this by exposing single interface?

Options:

1. Keeping two interface with `IReporter` and `IReporterNew : IReporter`
   Now all my new implementations require both the methods to be used.
2. Exposing two interface is not possible.

Comment: Is this interface consumed through a web service or something like that?

Comment: No this is exposed along with our deploy package

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just combine the interfaces into one *if the implementation of the method is on your end*. The user can decide then which to use. (Preferably you should mark the old method obsolete, thanks [3dd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308162/3dd))

```
public interface IReporter
{
    [Obsolete]
    void  Write(int site, DateTime start, DateTime end);
    void  Write(int site, SiteLocalDateTime start, SiteLocalDateTime end);
}
```

If that is not what you are after, you should in fact version your software. One version for new customers, one 'legacy' build for existing customers. Eventually you can migrate old customers to the new version.

You can even create a [conversion between the two types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) if the actual implementing type is known, but I am not sure if that is useful in this case.

Also, did you mean to use [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `SiteLocalDateTime`?

Answer (score 1):

This is always a possible issue when maintaining a public api. You cannot (or at least REALLY shouldn't ever remove anything that has been made public.

One common way to deal with this is to either add a new interface and mark the old one as deprecated, warning new customers not to use it, since it won't be supported in the future.

You could also do something similar and keep the old interface, but expose a new method using the new signature, plain old overloading. This would also be combined with marking the old method as deprecated.

It is of course theoretically possible to just delete the old interface/method entirely in the next version, but that will of course break client code. In most cases it is not worth it.